# flash generated system.img to Nexus S, then cannot boot up (stuck at *android* screen)

Tags: boot, android-build, android-2.3-gingerbread, nexus-s

I got android gingerbread source:
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b gingerbread && repo sync

Then, I built it：
lunch full_crespo-eng && make -j4

Then, I flash images:
fastboot flash system system.img && fastboot reboot

Then stuck at *android* screen, cannot boot the system up. Have you ever met this? What am I missing?

Build host: Ubuntu 12.04

Later edit: Fortunately I still can adb into the phone. I simply ps to list processes: I found it stopped at the point after zygote forking system_server. The system_server did not start other stuffs properly. Anybody saw this issue earlier? Any hint? Thank you

N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Get factory images, replace included system.img with the one just generated. Flash factory images.